# Как заставить rsync использовать .ssh/config?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, rsync

Я хочу синхронизировать локальную и удаленные директории с помощью rsync, но проблема в том, что подключение к удаленному хосту происходит через джамп сервер. Все это настроено в ssh конфиге. Можно сделать так чтоб rsync использовал ssh конфиг?

Comment: пример, как всё настроено в студию... по идее `rsync` и так должен «использовать `ssh`-конфиг»…

Comment: @Fat-Zer, не меня никаких настроек. Предположим у меня есть сервер, который в ssh конфиге назван dev1.  как мне синхранизировать диру ~/test1. Синхронизация должна происходить с локальной машины на удаленную

Comment: Пока не уточнишь, что именно и в каких конфигах у тебя настроено и как происходит подключение, под ответ подходит обычное `rsync ~/test1 dev1:/path/to/remote/dir`

Comment: @Fat-Zer лучше `rsync -a` ;)